# Use multiple initial conditions in parametric plots

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, boundary-conditions

I am plotting a 3d parametric plot for the set of my odes. I can use a single set of initial conditions to obtain a plot. I want to plot multiple initial conditions of my variables in a single 3d box. I want to give a set of initial conditions for this purpose. Here is my attempt:

```
H = Sqrt[(1/
  3)*(0.5/(a^6*V^2*Exp[6*t])*(P[t]^2 + 0.5*sig^2) + (0.25*m^2*
     M^2)*(1 - Exp[-1/(sig^2*M^2)]*Cos[2*\[Psi][t]/M]))];
eqs = {\[Psi]'[t] == P[t] Exp[-3 t]/(H a^3 V), 
   P'[t] == (-0.5/
       H) (a^3 V Exp[3 t] m^2 Exp[-1/(M^2*sig^2)] Sin[2 \[Psi][t]/M])};
```

In this step, I tried to do a self-thought attempt which I will write at the last. Right now, I can plot a single curve for the equation. I want multiple curves for different random values of the initial conditions.

```
sol = NDSolve[{eqs /. {M -> 0.5, m -> 10, V -> 1, a -> 1, 
      sig -> 10}, \[Psi][-10] == 1, P[-10] == 2}, {\[Psi], 
    P}, {t, -10, 10}, MaxSteps -> 2000000];

plot = ParametricPlot3D[{t, \[Psi][t], P[t]/Exp[3*t]} /. sol, {t, -10,
    10}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "\[Psi]", "P"}]
```

The attempt I tried to do was:

```
sol = NDSolve[{eqs /. {M -> 0.5, m -> 10, V -> 1, a -> 1, 
      sig -> 10}, \[Psi][-10] == a, P[-10] == b}, {\[Psi], 
    P},{a,-10,10},{b,-10,10}, {t, -10, 10}, MaxSteps -> 2000000];
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work. Please help in this regard,
TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ParametricNDSolve` can deal with such problem.

```
Clear[H, eqs, sol];
H = Sqrt[(1/
      3)*(0.5/(a^6*V^2*Exp[6*t])*(P[t]^2 + 0.5*sig^2) + (0.25*m^2*
         M^2)*(1 - Exp[-1/(sig^2*M^2)]*Cos[2*ψ[t]/M]))];
eqs = {ψ'[t] == P[t] Exp[-3 t]/(H a^3 V), 
   P'[t] == (-0.5/
       H) (a^3 V Exp[3 t] m^2 Exp[-1/(M^2*sig^2)] Sin[2 ψ[t]/M])};
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{eqs /. {M -> 0.5, m -> 10, V -> 1, a -> 1, 
      sig -> 10}, ψ[-10] == a, P[-10] == b}, {ψ, 
    P}, {t, -10, 10}, {a, b}];
ParametricPlot3D[{t, ψ[1, 2][t], P[1, 2][t]/Exp[3*t]} /. 
  sol, {t, -10, 10}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "ψ", "P"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the last line of the code, precisely? Secondly, how can I make a plot for a different value of the initial condition in the same figure?

Comment: @AhsanMujtaba For example, `ψ[1, 2][t] /. sol`  is the solution about `ψ` when `a=1,b=2`.

Comment: I think I have figured it out. Many thanks for your help, Mr. Cvgmt.